# Why does this loop not carry out all steps each time?

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve been writing a macro to format spreadsheets based on client preference. The part of the macro I’m having trouble with is getting percentage columns to format as percentages with one place after the decimal. In the code below, I determine where my % column will be (they’re headed with ‘Cov’ on the file I’m working in), and once that column is identified, the macro loops thru each row in the column and enters the % formula until the last row is reached.

Everything works mostly as intended, except the last two (2) columns that get the % formula do NOT update to show one place after the decimal. Can anyone provide insight to why the last two columns don't update the same as the others that are part of the loop?

Thank you!

```
For C = 24 To LastColumn + 2
    If .Cells(12, C) = "Cov" Then
    For i = 13 To LastRow
        Set formatCell = .Range(.Cells(i, C), .Cells(i, C))
        formatCell.Value = "=IFERROR(" & .Cells(i, C - 1).Address & "/" & .Cells(i, 14).Address & "*100,0)"
        formatCell.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    Next i
    End If
Next C
```

Comment: When you set a breakpoint and inspect `LastColumn` are the last two columns accounted for? Unrelated your line `Set formatCell = .Range(.Cells(i, C), .Cells(i, C))` can just be `Set formatCell = .Cells(i, C)`

Comment: JNevill - Thank you for the tip on the formatCell range! And yes, the last two columns are accounted for. When I go thru the macro step-by-step, the columns format to 1-point after the decimal as intended. But when I simply run the macro, those columns do not have anything after the decimal place. So as far as I can tell, the loop is working 100% as intended, but for some reason the numerical formatting isn't being retained.